# How to find CDH(Cloudera’s Distribution Including Apache Hadoop) version using HUE

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue

I've access only to HUE and am trying to find out CDH version using HUE.
Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find straight forward answer but this is how I found CDH version in Hue.

[image]

My CDH version is 5.14.2

Comment: I cannot find the about tab you are seeing in my version.